# Azure VNet Gateway Setup fails for second pair

Tags: powershell, azure

I am attempting to setup multiple VNet to VNet connections in Azure as described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/

I have 4 VNets

VNet-North
VNet-South
VNet-East
VNet-West

I have been trying to setup a star topology with a Domain Controller in the center like this:

[image: Star Topology]

I have successfully setup VNet-North to VNet-South in both directions.

When I try to connect VNet-North to VNet-East using this PoewerShell command:

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey -VNetName VNet-North -LocalNetworkSiteName VNet-East -SharedKey A1b2C3D4
```

It returns success

But when I try:

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey -VNetName VNet-East -LocalNetworkSiteName VNet-North -SharedKey A1b2C3D4

Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey : BadRequest: The specified local network site name 'VNet-North' is not    valid or could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey -LocalNetworkSiteName VNet-North -SharedKey AaBaCaDa -VNetN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.SetAzureVNetGatewayKey
```

Is a star topology possible?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, resolved by issuing `Reset-AzureVNetGateway -VNetName "Name"` against all parties having problem. This command will temporarily drop all connections on given VPN gateway, please use it with caution.